# String replaceall thread unsafe

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I know that the `Matcher` class is thread unsafe.

But is my method also thread unsafe? I think not.. Or please could you explain to me if it is..

```
private static String doSomething(String rawValue) {
        return rawValue.replaceAll("&","&amp;").replaceAll("#","&#35;")
                       .replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;")
                       .replaceAll("\\(","&#40;").replaceAll("\\)","&#41;");
    }
```

Comment: To be thread unsafe, you need to be reading a mutable value which is altered by a different thread.  So no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this method is thread-safe; it doesn't modify any shared data.

It's not safe to use the same `Matcher` instance in multiple threads, but it's fine to use different matchers in different threads at the same time.  Even if the `replaceAll` method uses a `Matcher` internally, it'll be a different instance for each call, which means different instances even if it's called by different threads at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an immutable object by reference.

The `replaceAll` method on the argument does not impact on the argument, it creates a new `String` instance.

To test this, you can do as follows:

```
String newValue = rawValue.replaceAll(...);
System.out.println(rawvalue); // old value
```

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher` class is not thread-safe, because its objects has internal state which can be modified concurrently if used in multiple threads.

The answer on your question depends on what exactly do you mean saying *thread-(un)safe*.

First point - `String` class objects are immutable in Java, methods that returns substring, replaces something in the original string, adds something etc - returns **brand new** `String`.

Second point - consider code like this using your method:

```
someOldStr = yourClass.doSomething(someOldStr);
if (newStr.contains("A")) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

I will blame this code for being data-race prone - `someOldStr` can be modified by several threads at once.

Conclusion: method **itself** is ok in my opinion as it doesn't use any external resources/variables/etc and deals with immutable object. Thread-safety on the program using it really depends on the method usage.